# Fotorama slider - how to Lazy Load images and then unload them when not visible?

Tags: image, out-of-memory, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, fotorama

I'm using [fotorama.io](https://fotorama.io/) on my site and I have a large gallery of images in the slider (60-80) so I followed the suggestion in the manual to use Lazy Load to not load all my images at once.

But when I browse images and already reached 40+ images, my browser memory is overloaded and the browser is starting to respond slowly, I have Memory Restart plugin for Firefox which shows my memory to build up very high.

Is there a way to use lazy load and keep for example 10 images, and unload all the not visible or images that are as far as 10+ to unload so that memory is cleared?

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting question! I don’t now is it possible to *unload* images from memory, I think browsers have to manage it automatically. By the way, Fotorama detaches invisible images. Аs I know it is the best practice for large galleries.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers load images even if they are removed with JavaScript. All images in the example below will be downloaded right away:

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <img src="1.jpg">
  <img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

If you don’t worry about browsers with no JavaScript, turn on lazy loading by altering your HTML:

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <a href="1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Add thumbnails:

```
<div class="fotorama">
  <a href="1.jpg" data-thumb="1_thumb.jpg"></a>
  <a href="2.jpg" data-thumb="2_thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

All fotoramas here are using this method of image embedding.

Comment: This is not working, chrome & firefox both load images

Comment: This "solution" was copied from here: https://fotorama.io/docs/4/lazy-load/. It doesn't work, don't waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

If want to lazy load on img tag just put the width and height.

Example :

```
<div class="fotorama" width="360" and height="360">
 <img src="1.jpg">
 <img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

And its work!

PS: Tested responsive website and all browsers.